# URL validation regex giving error in typescript

Tags: regex, url

I am trying to validate URL in typescript but I get below error whenever input filed is loaded in UI.

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^((https|http|ftp|smtp)://)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*/?(?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at Function.pattern (forms.js:1372)
    at SystemSettingsComponent.changeKeys (system-settings.component.ts:133)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SystemSettingsComponent.html:37)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
```

And Regex i am using is as below

```
^((https|http|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$
```

I tried many different regex but I am facing same issue in every regex for URL validation.

Testing URL Parameters are:

```
http://www.testdomain.site.com

https://www.testdomain.site.com

domain.testsite.com

http://www.testsite.com/path/to/dir/

https://www.testsite.com/path/to/dir/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
^((https|http|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$
```

you have unescaped `/`characters at least in the regex shown in the error and a missing `:` next to `?`, that's only asuggestion but this convert it to a non capturing group

this has nothing to do with typescript as the error says the problem commes from an invalid regex.

[example](https://regexr.com/5dsi1)

Comment: it is allowing 'testsite' simple string too which is incorrect atleast it should have www/ http:// before domain name please help